# Java Strip/Remove multiple words from a string

Tags: java, string, replace, split, formatting

How to strip a string like this:

```
String a = "ItemStack{DIAMOND_HELMET x 1,UNSPECIFIC_META:{meta-type=UNSPECIFIC, display-name=PRO, repair-cost=1}}"
```

I want to get something like

```
"Diamond_HELMET 1 UNSPECIFIC PRO"
```

The methods I have tried is just replacing a bunch of strings, but its a pain in the *** and looks awful. Just wondering if anyone have a better solution/option.
Sorry forgot to add my own code :/

```
    String itemStackStringName = "ItemStack{DIAMOND_HELMET x 1, UNSPECIFIC_META:{meta-type=UNSPECIFIC, display-name=PRO, repair-cost=1}}";
    String getItemStacks = itemStackStringName.replace("ItemStack","")
            .replace("{","").replace("}", "").replace("UNSPECIFIC_META:", "")
            .replace("display-name", "").replace("=","")
            .replace("meta-type", "").replace("repair-cost1", "")
            .replace("x", "").replace(",","");

    System.out.println(getItemStacks);
    "DIAMOND_HELMET  1 UNSPECIFIC PRO"
```

It works, but its just a huge mess.

Comment: From your question and example it is difficult to derive a pattern that could be used to extract the words. Please improve your question.

Comment: Regex would probably be your best friend. But as stated, without your attempted code, it's difficult to provide an adequate solution.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Code added

Comment: @StefanFreitag I need to store those in an array which i later can get, the "issue" is that my current method looks very messy and i was wondering if there is a way to achieve this easier.

Comment: @arkdevelopment I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that's the type your strings are going to be, you can go ahead and do something like this:

```
String arr[] = a.split("\\{");//you get an array of 3 strings
String someFinalString = arr[1].split("x")[0].trim();//you get "DIAMOND_HELMET"
someFinalString += arr[1].split("x")[1].split(",")[0];
arr = arr[2].split("\\=");//you get an array of 4 strings
someFinalString += " " + arr[1].split(",")[0] + " " + arr[2].split(",")[0];
```

In the future please post what you tried to do. Splitting something like this will always look awful. You can always make it concise later.

Just a proof this works (and you can figure out by yourself how to get lowercase I guess): [image: DrJava for simplicity]

Comment: String arr[] = a.split("\\{"); What does this exactly do?

Comment: String arr[] creates a null string array. a.split("\\{") splits a into strings divided by the character (here it's {). For brackets, the equal sign and the other special characters used by java, you have to use ("\\SPECIALCHAR") like I did with { od =, but if you're splitting by something else, like a comma (",") you don't need to use "\\".

So, basically, it split your strings into 3 strings that looked like this:
"ItemStack"
"DIAMOND_HELMET x 1, UNSPECIFIC_META:"
"meta-type=UNSPECIFIC, display-name=PRO, repair-cost=1}}"

So you see, the original String was separated into 3, by the {.